# How to show userform 1 time only

Tags: vba, excel

In VBA for excel, I have a userform then I want this to show only for 1 instance. Even if the user re-open it, it won't open again. Is there any code for it? well, I'm also using this code for my login:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

User.Caption = Environ("Username")

End Sub
```

I'm thinking if i can use this code in my problem. Hoping for a quick response. thanks guys, you're awesome!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible.

You have to add new sheet. In a cell `A1` type `0` (zero), then hide it. In a code which calls `UserForm`, use this:

```
Sub ShowMyForm()
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HiddenSheet").Range("A1")=0 then MyUserForm.Show
End Sub
```

In a form:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HiddenSheet").Range("A1")=1
    ThisWorkbook.Save()
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

Comment: The way that I do it is, I create a Name and check if the name exists :) That way no hidden sheet is required... And this works even when the user directly tries to launch the form from VBA :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, Thank you. A way you achieved that is very interesting. Cheers, Maciej

Comment: A similar question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940996/how-can-i-run-a-macro-as-a-workbook-opens-for-the-first-time-only/29941337#29941337

Comment: @Flephal, i'd suggest to notify questioner, not me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add an extra sheet just to store one bool, you can set a custom document property like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()    
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim test As Boolean
    test = Me.CustomDocumentProperties("UserFormShown").Value
    If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Sub
    UserForm1.Show
    Me.CustomDocumentProperties.Add "UserFormShown", False, msoPropertyTypeBoolean, True
End Sub
```

If the property hasn't been set yet it will throw an error, so trapping an error lets you know if you've set the property (and shown the form).