# Where name created with "Application.Names.Add" go?

Tags: vba, excel

For learning and work purposes I needed to create mesage box that pop-ups first only first time opening workbook. For that task I found elegant solution in one of the old treads  ([old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940996/how-can-i-run-a-macro-as-a-workbook-opens-for-the-first-time-only)).

Working principle of sugested code is more or less clear to me exept part where named created with Application.Names.Add go? I checked under Forlulas -> name manager and did not find created name, I gues it went somwhere else?

Used Code:

```
Sub RunOnce()
Dim Flag As Boolean: Flag = False
For Each Item In Application.Names
    If Item.Name = "FunctionHasRun" Then Flag = True
Next
If Flag = False Then
    Call Application.Names.Add("FunctionHasRun", True, False)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Call RunOnceFunction
End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: It's added to the workbook, but the final `False` argument means that it is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot see it in the Name Manager because your third argument, Visible:=False, is set False.

> Visible - True specifies that the name is defined as visible. False specifies that the name is defined as hidden. A hidden name does not appear in the Define Name, Paste Name, or Goto dialog box. The default value is True .

See [Names.Add Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.names.add) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is for a messagebox to pop up when the workbook is opened then the following code will do that for you, simply place it under `ThisWorkbook`.

Also I'm pretty sure the syntax in your code is incorrect, if you wanted to add a Named Range you would do it as follows: `Sheet1.Range("A1:Z10").Name = "MyNamedRange"` there would be no need for the **Call** before it, as it isn't calling another subroutine/function:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "This will pop up when the Workbook is opened!", vbInformation, "My MessageBox Title"
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

If you only want it to run the very first time the workbook is opened and then never again, the following will achieve that for you:

```
Sub RunOnce()
Dim Flag As Boolean: Flag = False
For Each Item In Application.Names
    If Item.Name = "FunctionHasRun" Then Flag = True
Next
If Flag = False Then
    Sheet1.Range("$A$1:$A$1").Name = "FunctionHasRun"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Call RunOnceFunction
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i think the OP wants `RunOnceFunction` to only run once ever (i.e. if reopened, don't run it)

Comment: @iamanigeeit thanks for the comment I misunderstood the actual question, I've now updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

`Formulas -> Names` only shows you the `ThisWorkbook.Names` and `Worksheet.Names` (depending on the scope of your `Name`).

If you insert a breakpoint and look at `View > Locals Window` you can find the `Application.Names` in `Me > Application > Names`.

My preferred method of adding an "opened" flag is to add to the `CustomDocumentProperties`. I've never seen anyone use `Application.Names` for this.